# Curiosity, how do you manage the Gutenberg block previews in the admin area?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-gutenberg

How can I manage gutenberg block previews in the admin area?
**Example**:
 If I have a block developed on bootstrap and with my custom css, in the admin area do you load bootstrap and your css to get the preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load custom css and javascript for every block like described in the [block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/applying-styles-with-stylesheets/). However it might not be a good idea to load bootstrap only for one block.

You can choose to supply `style` and `editor_style` in your `register_block_type` function. The first gets loaded in front + back, the latter only in the backend.

```
register_block_type( 'gutenberg-examples/example-02-stylesheets', array(
    'style' => 'gutenberg-examples-02',
    'editor_style' => 'gutenberg-examples-02-editor',
    'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-examples-02',
) );
```

Comment: Thanks, But how do you plan to manage the preview components based on bootstrap?